# Please confirm: Chromium is now ONLY 64-bit which is why there is no "64-bit" declaration

Tags: google-chrome, 64-bit, chromium

Sorry to sound so dense, but somehow got Chromium installed in an attempt to download the current Firefox update -- separate thread I am working on with Mozilla - read there is no longer any 32-bit Chromium versions which explains why, unlike current "About Chrome" data which declares the 64-bit version explicitly, Chromium only declares the version without a 64-bit designation.

Thanks

Comment: No, both are supported: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?arch=i386&keywords=chromium-browser

Answer (score 0):

Chromium binaries for i386 and many other architectures are alive and kicking: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?arch=i386&keywords=chromium-browser

You may be thinking of Google *Chrome* which is based on *Chromium* and only available for amd64 architectures on Linux.